# Using OpenCV official Matlab binding for cv.calcHist

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex

The Python's sample in *OpenCV-2.4.7\sources\samples\python2\color_histogram.py* has warking code below

```
h = cv2.calcHist( [hsv], [0, 1], None, [180, 256], [0, 180, 0, 256] )
```

**What is the corresponding syntax for Matlab mex binding?**

I tried different syntax such as

```
image = imread('coloredChips.png');
cv.imshow('main', image)
h = cv.calcHist({image}, [0 1], [], [180, 256], [0 180 0 256]);
h = cv.calcHist( image , [0 1], [], [180, 256], [0 180 0 256]);
```

And for every *calcHist* call got the error

```
Error using calcHist cv::exception caught: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:1421: 
error: (-215) nimages > 0 && dims > 0 in function cv::calcHist
```

The error is reproduced under:

1. OpenCV 3 latest sources from GitHub.
2. Compiler=VS2010 or VS2012.
3. Arch=x86 or x64
4. Configuration=Release
5. Matlab=R2013b

(Also, this question on **answers.opencv.org** [Matlab binding for cv.calcHist](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24498/matlab-binding-for-cvcalchist/))

Comment: Read mexopencv doc : http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/matlab/calcHist.html.

Comment: mexopencv library (author Kota Yamaguchi) is great, but not what I am asking about (see comment to your answer)

Answer (score 1):

inIf you read the [mexopencv documentation](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/matlab/calcHist.html), you can found an example at the end.

```
im = cv.cvtColor(im,'RGB2HSV');
edges = {linspace(0,180,30+1),linspace(0,256,32+1)};
h = cv.calcHist(im(:,:,1:2), edges);
```

You need to convert your image into HSV format. 
Since you have only 1 image, you use [0 1] for channel so as you can see in the example, he use the same as you. `im(:,:,1:2)`, by using channel 1 and 2 (Matlab indexing).

And after that all the `[], [180, 256], [0 180 0 256]` isn't the same as opencv. You have to pass edge as cell array like in the example.

**EDIT**

Another thing you can have a look. If you go in you mexopencv-master, you can go in src/+cv/calcHist.cpp and in this file you can see how the call to the OpenCV function is done.

It something like this :

```
calcHist(&arrays[0], arrays.size(), &channels[0], mask, hist, dims,
            &histSize[0], &ranges_ptr[0], uniform, accumulate);
```

Where hist, dims, histSize, range_ptr are declare on the upper part of the `mexFunction`.

Comment: You refer to mexopencv library written by Kota Yamaguchi, but I am interested in *official* OpenCV bindings (which are automatically generated similar to OpenCV Python's bindings) written by Hilton Bristow (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/matlab  http://answers.opencv.org/question/9487/matlab-api-for-opencv)

Comment: It okay, My fault. But same as I said in my edit. Try to have a look to the source. Maybe their something you can do with parameter, because mex return an OpenCV error and not a matlab one.